# How to add "adsbygoogle" AdSense property to the "window" global object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, global, adsense, window-object

I have a component that renders an `<AdSense/>` ad unit on my web app.

In `index.html` I have the following AdSense tag:

```
<script data-ad-client="XXXXXX" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

This script probably injects the `adsbygoogle` property to the `window` object.

But on my component, I have to use that property like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
},[]);
```

This was fine when my project was in **JavaScript**, but now that I've switched to **Typescript**, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR in src/components/ads/AdSenseBanner.tsx:74:13
TS2339: Property 'adsbygoogle' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
```

[image]

How can I declare this property to make Typescript understand what it is?

---

**What I've tried:**

I've created a `d.ts` for global declaration.

**AMBIENT.d.ts**

The following does not work.

```
declare const adsbygoogle: {[key: string]: unknown}[];
```

The following seems to work (as far as getting rid of the error). But it triggers a new error:

```
declare var adsbygoogle: {[key: string]: unknown}[];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article helped my to find a solution to this:

https://mariusschulz.com/blog/declaring-global-variables-in-typescript

**AMBIENT.d.ts**

```
interface Window {
  adsbygoogle: {[key: string]: unknown}[]
}
```

From that article:

> **Augmenting the Window Interface**
>
> Lastly, you can use TypeScript's interface declaration merging to let the compiler know that it can expect to find a property named **INITIAL_DATA** on the Window type and therefore the window object. To do that, you'll need to define an interface named Window with a property named **INITIAL_DATA**:
>
> [image]
>
> TypeScript will merge this interface definition together with the Window interface defined in lib.dom.d.ts, resulting in a single Window type. Now, the following assignment will no longer produce a type error:
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet is what I use...

```js
declare let adsbygoogle: any;
(adsbygoogle = (window as any).adsbygoogle || []).push({});
```

The top line can also be moved to a `.d.ts` file.